# Functions in fortran

Tags: function, fortran, gfortran

I am totally new in programming in fortran..... I tried to make a function, which is called in another program....

So I have my main Programm, which is called Spectrum.f:

```
      program Spectrum

       external I_Analytic
       double precision I_Analytic

       write(*,*) I_Analytic(5.D0)

      end
```

The function I_Analytic is defined in a second document, called Analytic.f:

```
       DOUBLE PRECISION function I_Analytic(w1)

        I_Analytic = w1**2

       end function I_Analytic
```

After compiling this program with
gfortran -o Spectrum Analytic.f Spectrum.f

I only get 0.0000000000 instead of 25....What is wrong with my program?

Comment: Do not learn `external` at this stage. Learn modules straight away. That's the right way I use in my classes. Also, use the free source forms. Use `IMPLICIT NONE` in all independent units (very important!) and learn kinds instead of `double precision`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not declare the type of `w1` so by the implicit typing rules it is `real`, not `double precision`. As I suggested in the comment, always use `IMPLICIT NONE`, and preferably also use modules to get an error if the interface does not conform.

Comment: @KobeGote I think you should not delete your answer, it is correct and two answers do not hurt. You were even slightly faster. But quite likely, we will find a duplicate and I may delete my answer too.